# Redirect to https all user agents instead of one specified

Tags: nginx

If nginx detect user agent as "someAgentX", don't redirect to https, stay on IP. Other agents redirect to https.
Something like this but this doesn't work.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /www;

  if ($http_user_agent ~* "someAgentX")
  {
       return 1;
  }
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
 ..and there is ssl config etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ($http_user_agent != "someAgentX")
  {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
```

Done it, and now works!